# Performance issue on the Simple SQL delete query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

Today i came across with one Performance issue with simple delete query.
I have two tables

```
 Table  Name : Attribute
 Column List : AttributeId Char(15), Desc Varchar(50)
```

This Attribute table contains only 15 rows.

Another Transaction table

```
Table Name : member
Column List : memid Int,  AttributeId Char(15), another set of 100 columns.
```

This transaction table AttributeId column has a Foreign key relation ship with Attribute table and this table contains more than 10000000 record and doesn't have any index on AttributeId column.
While we try to delete a record from the Attribute table, the delete query took around 3 min to complete execution.
if we disable the Foreign key constraint in the member table, same delete query executed in 10 ms.

So to improve the delete query performance, we decided to create non clustered index on the member.AttributeId column.

our question is, This member.AttributeId column has more null values (around 7500000 records). Can we create the non clustered index on this column.  Please share your inputs.

Comment: Yes you can create an index... you already did :) You might want to try creating a filtered index though

Comment: Along with filtered index, please use sparse column for null value column.

Comment: this post might help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497191/foreign-keys-slowing-down-delete